# My IP address changes without Dynamic IP active and on same network

Tags: security, ip

So I'm baffled, no dynamic IP is activated on either the router side or my local desktop side. I have to change my IP in Azure almost twice a day. I'm getting scared as it might be a security issue. I tried to write into a chat and it told me that I'm not allowed to use it, because I'm using a proxy, which I don't, not even VPN, so I'm asking you what I should do or if I should be scared?
(scanned the PC and there were no issues)

Answer (score 1):

IPs are not likely to change like that for residential users, you can double check however by logging into your modem and determining the IP of your WAN. This won't reveal the proxied IPs/etc, but what your ISP sent you.

If that's changing then sure, no issues but odd.

Now if that's fixed and it's still changing, you may have a proxy installed and forgot to turn it off.

I'd not worry personally but you could be subject to MITM man in the middle stuff. Best you can do is sort this and if you deem it to be MITM to just change passwords/etc ezpz.

Comment: Most times people installed a proxy/vpn not knowing and forgot to properly remove it and so it runs as an extension/app or something in the background. 

Sometimes people follow guides and setup manually not knowing, fairly harmless these days but I'd be concerned with how frequent you change cause services would default you as a bot.

Comment: Never touched a proxy and as for a VPN, I have Tunnel Bear, but it's not activated. Also the WAN Ip is different from my public IP. (100.x.x.x and 149.x.x.x)

Comment: Azure is cloud computing that "server" will have a different facing IP than you but if your IP is changing and you had tunnel bear on make sure it's properly removed. VPNs can save settings and forget to clear properly at times.